# Playwright: TypeError: when page.reload() or page.close()

Tags: typescript, firefox, webkit, playwright

i have a beforeEach section in my playwright Tests. In beforeEach for example i'm reloading page. When i run test on a local machine, i get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reload')`  in FireFox and WebKit but not always, 70% of the time. But when i run in CI 99% of the time beforeEach page.reload fails with same error. But i cun't guess what is the problem since all it has to do is reload page.

My test example:

```
test.beforeAll(async ({browser, user}) => {
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('/');
    let homePage = await pageManager.getHomePage(page);
    await homePage.Login(user.login, user.password);
    await expect(homePage.Lable.NavigationMenuHeading).toContainText(user.loginWelcomMessage, {timeout: 30000});
    mainMenu = await pageManager.getMainMenuComponent(page);
    checkableResultsPage = await pageManager.getCheckableResultsPage(page);
    await mainMenu.OpenMenuSection(mainMenu.MenuSections.MyCheckableResults);
    await expect(checkableResultsPage.DAPWidgets.EasyBusinessWins,
        '"Easy Business Wins widget should be visible').toBeVisible({timeout: 40000});
});

test.beforeEach(async () => {
    await page.reload();
});
```

**UPD:**

I fixed it with

```
if (page !== undefined)
   await page.reload();
```

But it is more like a crutch or temporary workaround and not a fix. I wonder what is causing page to become undefined only in firefox and sometimes webkit.